Python - import function from parallel directory
Let's assume I have two parallel directories, with simple python files.
--'dir_one' with file_one.py
--'dir_two' with file_two.py
In file_one.py there is a function named function_one.
How can I import it within file_two.py?
I have checked literally a few dozens of sources, including answers on stackoverflow. Therefore, I am not quoting any of them here. I have tried four different soulutions, none of them works.

Insert 'init.py' files in all the directories - results in error 'ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package'
Make both directories a single package - not possible in this case, directories have to be able to run as independent apps.
Use sys module: sys.path.insert(0, 'path-to-dir_one') right before 'import dir_one' line - doesn't change anything, still get 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dir_one'.
try relative import: 'from .dir_one import file_one' - 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zweizen.prodalitics'.

Is it possible at all to import a function in python from parallel folder without making it part of the same package?

The conventional way to do this would be to add the to dir_one as a dependency to the dir_two package metadata. All modern package managers (uv, Poetry …) should support this, and even pip does. — The upshot is: you would install the dir_one package in the environment of dir_two. You can use an “editable” dependency if you want to be able to see edits to dir_one “live” in dir_two.

"directories have to be able to run as independent apps" It is a strange requirement to let independent apps touch each other's code. You generally shouldn't do it.

You can add directly load the module to sys.modules using importlib to import it.
I assume you are working with a directory structure similar to this.

file1.py
a = 10

file2.py

import os

def import_from_path(module_name:str, file_path: str):
    import importlib.util
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, file_path)
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    return module

file_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../dir1/file1.py'))
module_name = "file1"

file1 = import_from_path(module_name, file_path)

print(file1.a)


You can import any python file as a module using this method and you don't modify the system path too.

Works! Another solution which worked was via importmonkey (pip install importmonkey; from importmonkey import add_path;
add_path("../src/project") ;
import mymodule). I like Vignesh suggestion more, as I do not have to rely on external module.

Just add "dir_one" to the Python path.
import sys
sys.path.append("../")

from dir_one import func_one


See my comment on the existing answer which provides the same solution (but much more detail and context).


⚠️ WARNING: Applications should never need to hack the sys.path. If
you need to modify it, do it via a wrapper (the way e.g. pytest does
it), not in the project code itself. If you do this your application now hard-codes a
package path to something outside its file system which is
incredibly brittle and just generally a terrible idea.

With that out of the way, here is a minimum reproducible example showing that your number 3 approach, which involves doing a "hack" where you modify the system path at runtime, should work.
Say you have the following directory structure:
project/
│
├── dir_one/
│   └── file_one.py
│
└── dir_two/
    └── file_two.py

With the content of dir_one/file_one.py:
def function_one():
  return 'Hello from function_one in file_one!'

You can add the path of dir_one to sys.path so python knows where to find file_one in dir_two/file_two.py:
import sys
import os

dir_one_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'dir_one'))
sys.path.insert(0, dir_one_path)

from file_one import function_one

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(function_one())

Output from running python file_two.py from within project/dir_two:
Hello from function_one in file_one!


Applications should never need to hack the sys.path. If you need to modify it, do it via a wrapper (the way e.g. pytest does it), not in the project code itself. Your application now hard-codes a package path to something outside of its file system. That’s incredibly brittle and just generally a terrible idea.

Got it just wanted to try write a minimum reproducible example proving it was possible.

They don't teach you how to write minimum reproducible examples like this in school. It's a lost art which I'm trying to practice.
